# Is arg-free repaint() better than repaint() with args?

Tags: java, performance, swing, graphics

I want to paint some things on a `JPanel` and read and excersied the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson. When it came to update the square using `repaint` I felt, that using this construct

```
private void moveSquare(int x, int y) {
  if ((squareX != x) || (squareY != y)) {
     squareX = x;
     squareY = y;
     repaint();
  }
}
```

provides for this specific example much better *paint performance* compared to this recommended one

```
private void moveSquare(int x, int y) {
  int OFFSET = 1;
  if ((squareX != x) || (squareY != y)) {
     repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW + OFFSET, squareH + OFFSET);
     squareX = x;
     squareY = y;
     repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW + OFFSET, squareH + OFFSET);
  }
}
```

If I use the latter one, the square looks during the drag process somewhat 'squashed'.

I know, this is a very basic example, but it makes somewhat scared of the Java Graphics performance in general.

Answer (score 0):

Doing twice the repaints is unnatural.

And when only repainting the union of old and new square?

```
private void moveSquare(int x, int y) {
  if (squareX != x || squareY != y) {
     final int OFFSET = 1;
     int minx = Math.min(x, squareX);
     int miny = Math.min(y, squareY);
     int dx = Math.abs(x - squareX);
     int dy = Math.abs(y - squareY);

     squareX = x;
     squareY = y;
     repaint(minx, miny, squareW + dx + OFFSET, squareH + dy + OFFSET);
  }
}
```

This should be smoother when the square is relatively small or outside the shown area (clipping).

Comment: It looks like this improves the rendering when moving right or down. Moving left or up still squashes the rectangle. I will investigate this further later.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the no-arg `paint()` and the one with arguments is that the one with arguments will set the clipping region in a subsequent call to `paint()`. The difference in paint performance, if any, will depend on whether the `paint()` method actually takes account of the clipping region, or just paints the whole drawing area and leaves the platform to work out whether the region needs updating or not.

Many Java AWT/Spring components ignore the clipping region, and just paint the whole area. It's sometimes quicker to do that, than to work out exactly how to repaint a very specific part of the display area. If the component is one you've written yourself, and you know you don't test the clipping region in `paint()`, then you know it doesn't make any different whether you call `repaint()` with arguments or not.

On the other hand, if you've gone to a lot of trouble with the `paint()` implementation, to work out exactly how to repaint a sub-region, then you owe it to yourself to try to work out how best to call `repaint()`.

If you didn't write the component, then there's probably know whether it's best to specify the repaint area or not except by testing, or close examination of the source code, if you have it.

If using `repaint()` with arguments causes a distorted image to be drawn, that probably points to a defective `paint()` implementation.

Comment: I use Swing and implemented ```paintComponent()``` only. As far as I understood this is the preferred 'Swing way'. I read that it is not recommended to implement paint under Swing.

Comment: `paintComponent()` is just the Swing equivalent of `paint()`. Whether you use AWT or Swing, the `Graphics` object passed to the method contains a clipping rectangle. In either case, you can use the clipping rectangle, or ignore it -- it's your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the clipping shape. I am totally new to painting and did not know that before. Unfortunately it does not make a difference: Using arg-free ```repaint()``` 'looks better' than just updating the clipping rectangle. I'll try to provide a full example, with all mentioned solutions.